# Migrate my Windows7 system to a pre-existing Windows8 system

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, migration

Is it possible to migrate all my applications and user settings between a Windows7 and Windows8 PC? Or is the only way to do that to upgrade my Windows7 PC to Windows8? I wondered if something similar to OSX Migration Assistant existed to facilitate this process.

I am moving from my old W7 desktop to a MacMini on which I already have a W8 VM running and it would be preferable not to have to port my W7 installation if possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Windows Easy Transfer to transfer your user settings (desktop items, app data, etc.), but not installed programs.

There is a decent guide to Windows Easy Transfer on [Bleeping Computer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/transfer-data-from-old-computer-to-windows-8/), but it boils down to this:

1. Open Windows Easy Transfer (it is already installed in Windows 7 and later)
2. Transfer data to an external drive (usb, or network if you're in that sort of environment)
3. Double clicking the file created by the wizard will open Easy Transfer to restore the data.